# Jenkins Docker Plugin - How to connect to Docker host securely

Tags: docker, security, ssl, jenkins, plugins

On the Docker host, I enable remote API with with the TLS option (i.e. create CA server/client keys to protect the daemon socket as described in https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/).  All is well.

Now, my question is, on the Jenkins side, with the Docker plugin, how do I configure this plugin so that it / Jenkins can connect to the Docker host securely with the certificate generated above?  Or better yet, what's the right / best method to configure Jenkins Docker plugin to securely connect to the remote Docker host?

Thanks.